# How to include a working hyperlink in Microsoft Teams webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

I created a `webhook` connector in one of my `Teams` channels. I'm now able to POST a message which appears on the channel with the following:

```
POST /webhookb2/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

{
    "text": "This is the BBC"
}
```

I now wish to edit it to include a hyperlink. I tried:

```
POST /webhookb2/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

{
    "text": "This is the <a href=\"www.bbc.com\">BBC</a>"
}
```

The problem was that BBC appeared like a hyperlink although when the cursor hovered over it, it was the same cursor icon as if hovering over any text string. Nothing happened when the link was clicked.

I then tried:

```
POST /webhookb2/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

{
    "text": "This is the [BBC](www.bbc.com)"
}
```

Again, BBC looked like a hyperlink and when the cursor hovered over it, it was the same cursor icon as if hovering over any text string. Also, nothing happened when I clicked it.

I then tried:

```
POST /webhookb2/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 570

{
    "type":"message",
    "attachments":[
        {
            "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "contentUrl":null,
            "content":{
                "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type":"AdaptiveCard",
                "version":"1.2",
                "body":[
                    {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "This is the [BBC](www.bbc.com)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Again, BBC looked like a hyperlink and this time the cursor turned to a hand pointing a finger as would expect for a hyperlink, however nothing happened when I clicked it.

How do I send a message that contains a working hyperlink?

Comment: Can you please change the text property value to this --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGfz0.png. Using https will make the hyperlink work.  As mentioned in this example payload you need to use https - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#:~:text=%5Bhttps%3A//adaptivecards.io/samples%5D(https%3A//adaptivecards.io/samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment from @Meghana-MSFT.

Answer (score 0):

Additional reference:
I was trying to send a link too but when I used the code provided for some reason my message was truncated. and the links didn't show up (maybe my message was too ling or something)

[image]

so I used a button for the download link instead and the problem was the same as @Meghana-MSFT comment, but I'm adding this as help to those who might need to send the link as a clickable button, not a hyperlink text:

```
{
        "type": "message",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
              "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
              "type": "AdaptiveCard",
              "version": "1.0",
              "body": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "***Daily Archive has been generated***"
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "title": "English Archive",
                            "url": `https://some.link`
                        },
                            {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "title": "Arabic Archive",
                            "url": `https://some.link`
                        }
                    ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
    }
```

result will look like this:

[image]